# logstash multiline pattern to detect lines that should be aggregated

Tags: pattern-matching, logstash, logback, multiline, syslog

I would like to detect lines that does not contain date and time in the following format which should be aggregated to the previous line:

```
28.04.2017;15:13:30.276
```

So I created a custom grok pattern like that:

```
MLINE %{MONTHDAY}\.%{MONTH}\.%{YEAR};%{TIME}
```

And this is my multiline configuration:

```
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "%{MLINE}"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
```

What I expected is that if the log line coming to logstash does not contain `%{MLINE}`, then it should be aggregated to the previous line.

But this is not happening and I do not understand why. Basically every log line is considered to be aggregated, and logstash will soon end due to cache limit.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: My mistake, there should be of course `%` instead of `$`. I edited the question. But still it does not aggregate correctly

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: Actually, if you are only using the `MLINE` pattern for multiline matching, naming will have no effect

Comment: Comments that made these comments intelligible have been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%{MONTH}` pattern matches words such as Aug, Feb, September. You want the `%{MONTHNUM}` pattern.

The pattern you want is:

```
MLINE %{MONTHDAY}\.%{MONTHNUM}\.%{YEAR};%{TIME}
```

I tested this using the [grok constructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match) which has a multiline tool.

Comment: @wiktor sorry about my grumpy Friday comments, thanks for the edit